# PHP get file name prefix?

Tags: php, regex, string, character, prefix

How can I get the prefix of the current page? i.e. if the current page is called `adm_panel.php`, I would just like to extract `adm_`. The prefixes for pages vary in length so doing a `substr` for the first `n` characters wouldn't work.

I can get the page name just fine:

```
<?php
    echo '<p>' . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '</p>';
?>
```

But am stumped about how to get the prefix. Any ideas? I was thinking maybe regex?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the separator always `_`? If so, `explode()` will work nicely.

Comment: `strtok` is sufficient. As would be `strstr` with `$before_needle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reset(explode('_',$filename));
```

or

```
substr($filename, 0, strpos($filename, '_'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using your `substr` version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

`^[^_]+`

This will match everything from the start to the first _ (not including the _)

Eg: adm

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wT6dK7)

To get the _ as well, change to regex to:

`^[^_]+_`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$filename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
echo '<p>' . substr($filename, 0, strpos($filename, '_') + 1) . '</p>';
```